Can I leave Incheon airport during layover as an Indonesian passport holder?
I'm an Indonesian passport holder. I'll be going round trip (USA-Indonesia) and transit in South Korea for 11 hrs. I want to leave the airport during my layover. Do I need a transit visa?

You don't need a visa in this specific situation (because you are in transit), as long as you have visa sticker from the US in your passport. Timatic says:

Visa required.
Visa Exemptions:
Nationals of Indonesia with an entry visa issued by Australia, Austria, Belgium, Bulgaria, Canada, Croatia, Cyprus, Czechia, Denmark, Estonia, Finland, France, Germany, Greece, Hungary, Iceland, Ireland (Rep.), Italy, Latvia, Liechtenstein, Lithuania, Luxembourg, Malta, Netherlands, New Zealand, Norway, Poland, Portugal, Romania, Slovakia, Slovenia, Spain, Sweden, Switzerland, USA or United Kingdom for a maximum stay of 30 days. They must:

arrive from the country that issued the visa and have a confirmed onward ticket for a flight to a third country within 30 days; or
arrive from a third country and have a confirmed onward ticket for a flight within 30 days to the country that issued the visa.

The entry visa must be in the form of visa sticker on the passport, except for Australian visas. If passengers have a transit point before arriving in Korea (Rep.) or after leaving Korea (Rep.), the maximum stay in that transit country must be within 3 days.


Even without a US visa / stamp, Indonesian citizens can transit through South Korea (Incheon airport) without a visa, up to 24 hours. In that case, you may not leave the airport transit area on your own, but you can do so as a member of an official tour group, for a small fee. Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_South_Korea
